# How to modify an array of objects response by changing object key names

Tags: javascript, callback

For the following, `source` is a function who's second argument is `response`, and `response` is also the callback function that is executed if the `$.getJSON` request succeeds, and thus performs correctly assuming the `/devices` endpoint provides the data in the correct format.

```
$( "#devices" ).autocomplete({
    source: function(request, response) {
        $.getJSON("/devices", { id: 123, term: request.term }, response);
    }
});
```

The `/devices` route will return something like `[{id:321, name:'the first name'}, ...]`, however, this is not in the correct format.

How can I modify this so the received data object keys will be changed from `name` to `value` so that `source` will be `[{id:321, value:'the name'}, ...]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the callback to be your own function which will modify the format of the data retrieved, and then call `response()` with the modified data:

```
$("#devices").autocomplete({
  source: function(request, response) {
    $.getJSON("/devices", {id: 123, term: request.term}, function(data) {
      const new_data = data.map(({name: value, ...r}) => ({value, ...r}));
      response(new_data);   
    });
  }
});
```

Above, the `.map()` is pulling out the `name` property (using [destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment)) and renaming it to `value`. The `...r` is using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and is used to extract the remaining keys/values from the original object. So `r` is an object which contains everything but the `name` property for a given element. The function then returns a new object, using [short hand property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015) to set `value` as a key (with its contents being the actual value), merged with the remaining part of the object (so `...r` is used to spread/merge the keys/values of object `r` into the newly created one - it behaves similarly to `Object.assign`)

Comment: Thanks Nick,  I was going down this path but didn't do the final calling `response()` with the modified data nor use `...`.  Off topic, but would you please explain how `.map` is working with emphasis on what `...` is doing?

Comment: @user1032531 No worries. I’ve updated my answer to include an explanation on how the .map works (I’m currently on my mobile so I might edit it for clarity when I’ve got access to a desktop)

Answer (score 0):

I guess you could loop through the response array using array.forEach();

```
response.forEach(e => {
  e.value = e.name;
  delete e.name;
});
```